# Open two sidebar tabs at once vs code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a way to display the files tab and debugger at once in vs code?

I can't seem to find a way to do it.

I want two tabs on the left, one with files and one with the debugger both open at once. I've tried looking in View settings but its only able to split editors.

Answer (score 2):

You can drag one of the bars to the Panel, or you have to do it a View at a time.

Comment: what do you mean the panel? I wont let me drag it to open it anywhere.

Comment: The Panel is the part with the Terminal and the Debug output, the Views you can drag and drop

Comment: This is, as far as I can tell, incorrect — unless the behaviour was removed in a later version. For example, selecting "Explorer (⇧⌘E)" in the Activity Bar, I cannot then drag the sidebar header (saying "EXPLORER") anywhere at all; much less into the Panel located at the bottom (or side) of the window.

Comment: @ELLIOTTCABLE this is because `Explorer` is the ViewContainer, that can not be moved, you can drag/drop Views like `OUTLINE`, `TIMELINE`, `OPEN EDITORS` and the View with the workspace directory tree with the workspace name in the title bar